# Android: copying populated sqlite database from assets folder not working correctly and causing errors

Tags: android, sqlite

*****I FIGURED IT OUT*********
sorry to waste anyone's time but I figured out what I was doing wrong. I was using the line, dbcontext.deletedatabase("tupperware.db") because I thought it would delete my pixel xl stored database so that the new one could be copied from assets. I still don't fully understand how it works but apparently that line was interfering with the database copy and causing an empty database with no tables to be copied. I tried to copy the database without this line of code and it copied over and my app now works again. Thanks for everyone's help!!! Below this line is the original question I asked*****************************

I am working in android studio 3.1.4 on an app that uses a sqlite database.

I am testing the app on my google pixel XL phone running android version 9.

I wanted to delete the database using code and then copy another database (with equivalent name and tables...just less data) from the assets folder in android studio to pixel xl so my app can access it. When I tried this the app now crashes giving me the following error...

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: container (code 1 
SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling:
```

I wrote some code to check if the database exists and it returns "true" indicating the database exists. Also, in android studio, I opened View>Tool Windows>Device File Explorer and I can see the database is where it should be (in data/data/MY PACKAGE INFO/databases) along with the same database with a db-shm and db-wal extension. However, I noticed that the database was only 12kb where the database I placed in the assets folder is 156kb so I saved the 12kb database to my computer and opened it using DB Browser for Sqlite and discovered that the database is empty. It has no tables or data in it. So I want to know what I am doing wrong. Why is the database copying over incorrectly (i mean copying over with no tables or data)????

Here are some things I have tried...

-I have found several similar questions on stackoverflow but none of them offered any information that has solved my problem.

-I have uninstalled the app from my phone and reinstalled it (many times).

-I have cleared the cache for the app as well as deleted the data for it (also many times).

-I have tried various lines of code that you can see below that I have now commented out

-I have compared my code to copy the database to others here on stackoverflow and it is almost exactly the same. I haven't found any obvious errors.

-I have tried changing the database version number in my code

-I have checked my permissions to make sure the app can access storage on my phone

-I have tried copying several different databases with the same name and equivalent tables (all sqlite databases)

Here is my code that copies the database...

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String DB_NAME = "tupperware.db";
    private static String DB_PATH = Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/data/com.bignerdranch.android.tupperwarelayout/databases/";
    //private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.bignerdranch.android.tupperwarelayout/databases/";

    private SQLiteDatabase tuppDatabase;

    private final Context dbContext;

    public DatabaseHelper (final Context context){
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 5);
        this.dbContext = context;
        //dbContext.deleteDatabase("tupperware.db"); //USE THIS IF YOU MESS THE DATABASE UP AND YOU NEED TO REINSTALL IT.
        Log.i("DB_PATH", DB_PATH);
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        Log.i("DATABASE EXIST", "boolean dbExist is " + dbExist);

        if (dbExist){
            //do nothing because the tupperware.db exists
        }else{
            //File file = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            //this.getWritableDatabase();
            try{
                copyDataBase();
                this.close();
            }catch (IOException e){
                Log.i("THE_ERROR", e.toString());
                throw new Error("Error copying new database");
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase(){
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try{
            String myDBPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            File file = new File(myDBPath);
            if (file.exists() && !file.isDirectory())
                checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myDBPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        }catch (SQLiteException e){
        }

        if (checkDB != null){
            checkDB.close();
        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = dbContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0){
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String dbPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        tuppDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        tuppDatabase.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
    }
}
```

Access to the database has worked perfectly for around 6 months now so I have no idea what to do at this point. Please let me know if you can help. Thanks!!!!

Comment: Use RoomDB to solve it handle such errors

Comment: *I can see the database is where it should be ... along with the same database with a db-shm and db-wal extension*... Did you just copy the database when something has it open in WAL journal mode? That's a great way to lose data at best, completely corrupt the copy at worst. Either make sure nothing had the database open before copying, or use the sqlite3 shell's `.backup` command to copy it.

Comment: If you want to do it from your own program, see if the sqlite binding you're using supports the [online backup API](https://www.sqlite.org/backup.html) (which is what .backup in the shell uses).